# How to suppress unchecked class warning

Tags: java, gson

how to I pass `HashMap<String, String>.class` in Gson builder for supperss "unchecked warning"?

```
HashMap<String, String> manifest = 
    Gson().fromJson(stringBuilder.toString(), HashMap.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Mark your method with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

Comment: Just to add to this perfectly fine answer: [Javadoc Predefined Annotation Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` above your Hashmap reference. This will only ignore the next statement to it instead of whole method.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 

HashMap<String, String> manifest = 
        Gson().fromJson(stringBuilder.toString(), HashMap.class);
```